# Adding new files to Application Storage Directory with AIR application installer

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air

I have an AIR app that gets bundled with XML files that the app needs.  These get put into the APP Storage Directory, of course.  Works great.  But when I install a new version ( which includes new XML files) , the new files don't get added or overwrite the ones from the previous version.  It seems that if that directory is there from a previous install, the installer will ignore the part where it moves included files.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I was doing wrong.  I didn't realize that the files also get copied to ApplicationDirectory.  These files do get updated on new installs so accessing them from there instead of storage was the key. It does make sense to not futz with the storage dir on uprades so the users pref files etc don't get deleted.